# Adding MatBlazor MatThemeProvider in MainLayout.razor or App.razor

Tags: html, blazor, matblazor

The MatBlazor documentation says to "To apply theme for all application you can use MatThemeProvider in MainLayout.razor or App.razor"

The example is pretty thin on information.

It just does not work when adding the code snippet to either MainLayout.razor or App.razor.

The error I get is
    "InvalidOperationException: The Router component requires a value for the parameter Found."

How do you apply a theme for the whole app?

App.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">

        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <Authorizing>
                <p>Determining session state, please wait...</p>
            </Authorizing>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <Unauthorised />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>

        <MatThemeProvider Theme="@theme">
            <Router AppAssembly=typeof(Pages.Dashboard).Assembly />
        </MatThemeProvider>

    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code
    {
    MatTheme theme = new MatTheme()
    {
        Primary = MatThemeColors.Orange._500.Value,
        Secondary = MatThemeColors.BlueGrey._500.Value
    };
}
```

Comment: `The Router component` are you sure this is about matblazor? Please show how and where you added `MatThemeProvider`, but it looks like there's another problem

Comment: See updated code. If I remove the <MatThemeProvider> then everything works OK.

Comment: What about when putting it in the `MainLayout` and removing it from the code you updated in your question?

Comment: Same thing - unsure how I am getting this so wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this?

```html
<MatThemeProvider Theme="@theme">
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">

        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <Authorizing>
                <p>Determining session state, please wait...</p>
            </Authorizing>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <Unauthorised />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>  
    <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</MatThemeProvider>

@code
{ 
    MatTheme theme = new MatTheme()
        {
            Primary = MatThemeColors.Orange._500.Value,
            Secondary = MatThemeColors.BlueGrey._500.Value
        }; 
}
```

Please let me know if it works. :)